# read file character by character for char and the number set for numbers

Tags: c

Is there a way to read a file character by character for chars and the number set for numbers?

```
bob 4567
joe 39083
sara 4239824
```

That is my file

```
while ((c = fgetc(pFile)) != EOF)
{
    //my work
}
```

I know this works on my chars. This won't read numbers in the way I want. This reads b,o,b,space,4,5,6,7. I want it to read b,o,b,space,4567. The reason for this is I will be adding the 4567 plus 39083 plus 4239824 eventually.

UPDATE 12-20

If the the file is NOT consistent all the the way through can fscanf handle it? Sometimes the file is "word number" and other times it is just "word". Like this.

```
bob 456
echo
cat 
dog 1101
peacock 300
```

This seems to be working and I am surprised by this. I didn't think fsacnf liked files that were inconsistent.

```
while (fscanf(pFile, "%s %d",  nam, &val) !=EOF)
{
    //my work
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can read the digits into an array, then convert that to an `int` with `atoi` or (preferably) `strtol`.

Alternatively, you could read the letters, then stop when get to the space, and read the number with something like `[f]scanf` (or you could just read it all with `[f]fscanf`, of course).

Edit:

Given a choice, I'd probably do something like:

```
char name[16];
int number;

fscanf(input_file, "%15s %d", name, &number);
```

Comment: `atoi` was actually what I planned on using. Unfortunately it seems fgetc really doesn't like numbers. Somehow it turned 25 into 2,50,5,53. I really don't understand how this is possible.Could you explain what you recommend with fscanf?

Comment: Can fsanf handle inconsistent files? This is what I did and I am surprised I didn't have any issues. `while (fscanf(pFile, "%s %d",  nam, &val) !=EOF)`.

Comment: @cokedude: Yes and no. What'll happen is that fscanf will fail to convert the integer, in which case it'll return without modifying the existing value of `number`. You could into a problem if the string is missing though. In that case, the number would be read as a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

enum { SPACE, STRING, NUMBER, END };

int main(void){
    FILE *pFile = stdin;//Mock
    char buffer[32];
    int i, c, kind, number;
    unsigned long long sum =0;

    i = 0; kind = SPACE;
    while((c = fgetc(pFile)) != EOF){//&& i< suzeof(buffer)
        buffer[i] = c;
        if(isdigit(c)){
            kind = NUMBER;
            ++i;
        } else if(isspace(c)){
            buffer[i] = '\0';
            if(kind == STRING){
                printf("%s\n", buffer);
            } else if(kind == NUMBER){
                number = atoi(buffer);
                printf("%d\n", number);
                sum += number;
            }
            kind = SPACE;
            i = 0;
        } else {
            kind = STRING;
            ++i;
        }
    }
    printf("sum : %llu\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: note : result if the buffer is full is not correct. The line is ignored if there is no new line to the last line.

Comment: After I compile and run the program I know I need to type something. What do I want to do after I have typed all I want to type? I have tried enter multiple times, \n, EOF, 0, 1, and, 2. I am not sure how to finish it except hitting ctrl + c and killing the program.

Comment: @cokedude There is no problem if the file pointer is file pointer by `fopen` real. If you have to `stdin` as sample then input  `CTRL+Z` (for windows) or `CTRL+D` (for unix clan).